# HTML button click change the background color of the row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button

I have an HTML table that has a button on every row. The objective here is when a button is clicked, the whole row will got the background color changed. 
The code is:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Value1</td>
        <td>Value2</td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="press" onclick="myFunction(this)" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Value3</td>
        <td>Value4</td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="press" onclick="myFunction(this)" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction(e) {
        //change the background color of the row
    }
</script>
```

Can you help me with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use **class** instead and for good practise remove the inline function calls inside your html.

**Use this:**

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Value1</td>
        <td>Value2</td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="press" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Value3</td>
        <td>Value4</td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="press" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**jQuery**

```
var all_tr = $('tr');
$('td input[type="button"]').on('click', function () {
    all_tr.removeClass('selected');
    $(this).closest('tr').addClass('selected');
});
```

### Demo [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/rZqLX/1/)

(updated)

Comment: Now, what I want is when I press another button, the background color of the previous row returned back to default so that the current row got highlighted. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Might I also suggest `table { padding:0px;border-collapse: collapse;}` to get rid of those crummy white lines if you're going to highlight the whole row.  See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/8vFJA/)

Comment: ahhh...so nice!  Also, great answer.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery's `closest` method is perfect for this, since you included `jQuery` in your tags:

```
function myFunction(el) {
//change the background color of the row

  $(el).closest('tr').css('background-color', 'red');
}
```

in non-jQuery fashion, you can:

```
function myFunction(el) {
//change the background color of the row
  while (el && (el.tagName.toLowerCase() != 'tr'))
    el = el.parentNode;

  if (el)
    el.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
```

Comment: +1 for `closest` as the most robust answer. Input needn't be nested exactly two levels below tr, so `.parent().parent()` answers might break in the future.

Comment: Now, what I want is when I press another button, the background color of the previous row returned back to default so that the current row got highlighted. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Better off adding a class to the selected row, then (a better practice, anyway) and setting the background color on that. Removing the class from others is covered in various questions, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683178/how-to-remove-a-css-class-from-all-same-level-table-rows-when-a-row-is-selected

Answer (score 2):

you can use these solution with jQuery.

```
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    $('table input').bind('click', function (e) {       
        $(this).parent().parent().addClass('redBackground');    
    });
  </script>
```

Create CSS class, I named it 'redBackground'.

```
<style type='text/css'>
   .redBackground {
       background: #fff;
   }
</style>
```

Regards.

Comment: The `parent` of the sending element, input, is just the particular `td` cell that it lives in.  This will only change that cell's color, not the whole row. See @crowebird's response by going up two parent levels and using the child css selector.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way you could do it: http://jsfiddle.net/69sU7/

```
myFunction = function(btn) {
    $(btn).parent().parent().addClass('highlight');
}
```

When the button is clicked, using jQuery, we capture the btn itself, then grab its parent (`td`), and grab its parent (`tr`).  We then add the class `highlight` to that `tr`.

The `.highlight` class adds to all the `td`'s below it, a background of yellow.

Comment: Now, what I want is when I press another button, the background color of the previous row returned back to default so that the current row got highlighted. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Use direct property backgroundColor

```
e.parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = '#ff0';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cguLU/1/

To reset other rows in the table do:

http://jsfiddle.net/cguLU/2/

```
function myFunction(e) {
  var tr = e.parentNode.parentNode;
  var table = e.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;    
  //set current backgroundColor
    var len = table.childNodes.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      if (table.childNodes[i].nodeType == 1) {
        table.childNodes[i].style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
      }
    }
    tr.style.backgroundColor = '#ff0';
}
```

Comment: Now, what I want is when I press another button, the background color of the previous row returned back to default so that the current row got highlighted. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Use this http://jsfiddle.net/4P3Jb/

```
e.parentNode.parentNode.style.background = "red";
```