# Angular Changing the Background Color of a Row When Its Button is Clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

In my code, I have a list and every row has a button that opens a sidebar. Since the list has too many elements inside it, I want the background color of the row to turn yellow when I click its own button, just to remember what I have clicked. Here is my code for the table and button. Right now, when I click the button, the whole list turns yellow. How can I fix that and, what should I do to achieve what I want?

HTML:

```
<div class="content">
    <div fxLayout="row">
        <!-- CONTENT -->
        <div fxFlex class="px-8" fxLayout="column" fusePerfectScrollbar>

            <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="end" class="mat-elevation-z4 responsive-grid">
                <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="end" class="pr-4">
                    <mat-form-field fxFlex fxFlex.gt-sm="30">
                        <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filtrele">
                    </mat-form-field>
                </div>
                <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="stock-table" id="pool-row">
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="Reference">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
                            Reference </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let i = index">
                            <p *ngIf="controlReferanceColor(row)" style="color:red;">{{row.Reference}}
                            </p>
                            <p *ngIf="!controlReferanceColor(row)">{{row.Reference}}</p>
                        </td>
                    </ng-container>
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="Actions">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
                            <a mat-icon-button matTooltip="Detay" *ngIf="row.SourceType?.Id != 32"
                                [routerLink]="getLink(row)" target="_blank">
                                <mat-icon>open_in_browser</mat-icon>
                            </a>
                            <button mat-icon-button matTooltip="Liste" *ngIf="row.SourceType?.Id == 32" id="list"
                                class="sidebar-toggle" (click)="getReferenceList('lab-test-detail-preview',row)">
                                <mat-icon>pageview</mat-icon>
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </ng-container>                        
                    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
                    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"
                        [ngClass]="{'amber-fg': controlReferanceColor(row) == true}"></tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <mat-paginator class="mt-4" [pageSizeOptions]="[20, 40, 80 , 120]"></mat-paginator>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

TS:

```
getReferenceList(sidebarName: string, reference: IProcess) {
    if (reference && reference.Reference != "") {
        this.selectedProcessList = this._stockService.processList.find(
            (x) => x.Reference === reference.Reference
        ).ChildProcessList;
        this._fuseSidebarService.getSidebar(sidebarName).open();
        document.getElementById('pool-row').style.backgroundColor = '#fced49';
    }
}
openSidebar(name: string, stockEntryId: number): void {
    //this.previewStockEntryId = stockEntryId;
    this._fuseSidebarService.getSidebar(name).open();
   
}
```

Comment: could u provide stackblitz?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18518812/html-button-click-change-the-background-color-of-the-row

Comment: I've edited my code. Now, the whole list turns yellow, how can I only color in the row I have selected?

Comment: `[ngClass]="{ 'selected': row === selectedRow }"` this way you can add selected css class to only row you have clicked on

Comment: @GaurangDhorda Thanks, but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion below has worked for me with Material tables and will work if your data source objects have a unique record identifier.

In order to set the CSS style for the currently selected table row, leaving the other rows in an unselected CSS style try the following (some properties may vary slightly like the id of each object):

Create CSS styles to indicate selected and unselected:

`CSS`

```
.selectedClass
{
    background-color: yellow;
}

.unselectedClass
{
    background-color: beige;
}
```

In the HTML template, for each mat-cell table cell definition, add the conditional `[ngClass]` as shown:

`HTML`

```
...
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" 
    [ngClass]="{ 'selectedClass': element.selectedRow === element.id, 
             'unselectedClass': element.selectedRow !== element.id }">
    <a mat-icon-button matTooltip="Detay" *ngIf="row.SourceType?.Id != 32"
            [routerLink]="getLink(row)" target="_blank">
                <mat-icon>open_in_browser</mat-icon>
    </a>
    <button mat-icon-button matTooltip="Liste" 
        *ngIf="row.SourceType?.Id == 32" id="list"
        class="sidebar-toggle" 
        (click)="getReferenceList('lab-test-detail-preview',row)">
        <mat-icon>pageview</mat-icon>
    </button>
</td>
```

In the typescript source, add or map an additional property, `selectedRow` to the structure containing the data source as shown:

`TS`

```
export interface DataSource
{
  id: number;
  reference: string;
  actions: string;
    ...
  selectedRow: number;
}
```

Where `id` is your record key.

In the event handler for the button click, reset (set to zero) all `selectedRow` values in each object within the data source, and set the `selectedRow` value
for the currently selected object to the record's `id` value as shown:

```
getReferenceList(action: string, row: DataSource)
{
    ...
    this.dataSource.map(e => { e.selectedRow = 0 });
    row.selectedRow = row.id;
    ...
}
```

The above will render the style for the selection class for the currently selected table row, and render the style for the un-selection class for the rows not currently selected.

Each table cell column for each element will need to have the conditional class applied to it in order for the element's entire row's style to change to the selected CSS style.